# Alternatives to port forwarding

Tags: .net, tcp, port, nat, portforwarding

I've written a web server for my application that needs to be accessible remotely over the web. I'm currently using UPNP to do this via port forwarding but i'm wondering if there is any other way (relying on IPv6 is not an option). I've looked into STUN/ hole punching but it seems that you need a "smart" client on the other end to handle the connection and all I have to work with is a web browser. I've also looked into HTML5 sockets but it seems that it's bleeding edge chrome only stuff at the moment.

Basically is there some other option I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

STUN/Hole Punching is primarily for UDP but you need something for TCP. There is a TCP version of STUN called STUNT but that is not an option in your case as you need smart logic that can't be implemented in plain browser without any active-x or extension. As you mentioned that IPv6 is not an option for you so you only have one option here.
-- Your web-server need to be on Public IP address.

Either you host your web-server directly on Public IP, or you use port forwarding from Public interface to your web-server. There's no other option in your case !!